# Wordpress custom post type permalink rewrite posts issue

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, custom-post-type

I have just managed to rewrite the URL permalink structure for my custom post types which is working just the way I want, however since adding these rewrites my blog posts have started going to a 404 page.

in my functions.php file I have:

```
'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => '%companies%/projects', 'with_front' => false),
```

this is within my Custom Post Type where I registered it.

At the bottom of my functions.php I have this snippet:

```
function wpa_show_permalinks( $post_link, $post ){
    if ( is_object( $post ) && $post->post_type == 'projects' ){
        $terms = wp_get_object_terms( $post->ID, 'companies' );
        if( $terms ){
            return str_replace( '%companies%' , $terms[0]->slug , $post_link );
        }
    }
    return $post_link;
}
add_filter( 'post_type_link', 'wpa_show_permalinks', 1, 2 );
```

I can't see a reason why this would be affecting my posts? I have saved the permalinks via the admin.

Comment: Code seems okay. Are you sure it's not related to something else? Does it work when you remove this?

Comment: Did you try https://typerocket.com/flushing-permalinks-in-wordpress/ ?

Comment: update permalink structure see if it solves the problem

Comment: Yes when I remove the code the blog posts work fine.

Answer (score 0):

I have done similar on my website earlier, so I tried rewriting my code to follow your structure, but you should take a look at variables and replace custompost and custompost-types with yours data.

Originally posted in my blog: https://windowspros.ru/url-rewrites-custom-post-type-permalinks-wordpress/

```
// REMOVE OLD PERMALINKS IF EXSIT

add_action( "after_setup_theme", 'custom_remove_permalink', 1);
function custom_remove_permalink(){
    remove_action( "after_setup_theme", 'active_permalinks');
}

// CREATE CUSTOM RULES

add_action( "after_setup_theme", 'custom_active_permalinks');
function custom_active_permalinks() {
    global $wp_rewrite;
    $wp_rewrite->add_rewrite_tag("%custompost%", '([^/]+)', "custompost=");
    $wp_rewrite->add_rewrite_tag( "%custompost-type%", '(.+?)', "custompost-type=" );
    $wp_rewrite->add_rewrite_tag( "%companies%", '(.+?)', "companies=" );
    $rewrite_args = array();
    $rewrite_args['walk_dirs'] = false;
    add_rewrite_rule( '([^/]+)/projects/?$', 'index.php?category_name=$matches[1]&post_type=custompost', 'top' );
    $wp_rewrite->add_permastruct('custompost', '%companies%/projects/%custompost%', $rewrite_args);

}

// Make sure that all links on the site, include the related texonomy terms

add_filter( 'post_type_link', 'custom_custompost_permalink', 10, 2 );
function custom_custompost_permalink( $permalink, $post ) {
    if ( $post->post_type !== 'custompost' ) {
        return $permalink;
    }

    $companies = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'company', true );

    if ( ! $companies ) {
        $permalink = str_replace( '%companies%', 'defaultvalue', $permalink );
    } else {
        $permalink = str_replace( '%companies%', $companies , $permalink );
    }

    $terms = wp_get_post_terms($post->ID, 'custompost-type', array( 'orderby' => 'parent', 'order' => 'DESC' ));

    if ( ! $terms ) {
        $permalink = str_replace( '%custompost-type%', '_yoast_wpseo_primary_category', $permalink );
    } else {
        $permalink = str_replace( '%custompost-type%', $terms[0]->slug , $permalink );
    }

    $authordata = get_userdata($post->post_author);
    $author = $authordata->user_nicename;
    if ( ! $author ) {
        $permalink = str_replace( '%author%', 'author', $permalink );
    } else {
        $permalink = str_replace( '%author%', $author , $permalink );
    }

    return $permalink;
}
```